# No migrations to apply but Django is still trying to create a new content type

Tags: python, mysql, django

I pushed a new release to a server last week which included a database migration for a new table. This completed as expected, and works, but now on every deployment when the server runs it's migrations I'm seeing no migrations to apply, but also a unique key error on content types;

```
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.
...
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.IntegrityError
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'djangocms_newsletter-signup' for key 'django_content_type_app_label_45f3b1d93ec8c61c_uniq'")
```

The table is in the database, the content type for the `Signup` model is in the content types table, the migration is in the migrations table... so why does Django try to create a new content type still?

Migrations are ran as part of a straightforward post deployment script that I use for all projects;

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

PROJ_PATH=/var/www/django/myproj

cd $PROJ_PATH

echo 'clear-out...'
find $PROJ_PATH -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -rf '{}' ';'
find $PROJ_PATH -name "*.pyo" -exec rm -rf '{}' ';'

echo 'set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="project.settings.local_override"

echo 'activating...'
source ../bin/activate

echo 'pip install...'
pip install -r requirements.txt --no-deps

echo 'migrate...'
python manage.py migrate --noinput

echo 'collectstatic...'
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

echo 'restart apache...'
sudo service apache2 restart

deactivate
```

At the moment, I've been clearing the app name from the existing content type in order to allow the deployment to succeed, but now I just want to understand what the issue is so that I can resolve it in future.

Full Traceback;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 165, in handle
emit_post_migrate_signal(created_models, self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 268, in emit_post_migrate_signal
using=db)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 198, in send
response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/management.py", line 56, in update_contenttypes
ContentType.objects.using(using).bulk_create(cts)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 409, in bulk_create
self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 938, in _batched_insert
using=self.db)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 921, in _insert
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 921, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 129, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/var/www/django/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'djangocms_newsletter-signup' for key 'django_content_type_app_label_45f3b1d93ec8c61c_uniq'")
execute bash /var/www/django/myproj/myproj/shell_scripts/production_post_deployment.sh
```

Comment: Content types are created in a `post_migrate` signal handler, which explains why it happens even if there are no migrations to apply. It doesn't explain the bug, it should never try to create existing content types. Can you show the complete traceback? You might have to run `manage.py migrate` with the `--traceback` flag.

Comment: @knbk thanks, I thought that was the case. I've added the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After coming across this issue again I've debugged it using the shell on the server as it's not been possible to reproduce & found that the issue is caused by cached ContentType objects.

Let me illustrate;

```
>>> content_types = dict((ct.model, ct) for ct in ContentType.objects.filter(app_label='consoles'))
>>> content_types
{}
>>> content_types = dict((ct.model, ct) for ct in ContentType.objects.filter(app_label='news'))
>>> content_types
{u'latestnews': <ContentType: latest news>}
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.clear()
>>> content_types = dict((ct.model, ct) for ct in ContentType.objects.filter(app_label='consoles'))
>>> content_types
{u'runner': <ContentType: runner>, u'importedclient': <ContentType: imported client>, u'placetype': <ContentType: place type>, u'invoice': <ContentType: invoice>, u'placetypetotal': <ContentType: place type total>, u'clientconsoles': <ContentType: client consoles>, u'emailtemplate': <ContentType: email template>, u'event': <ContentType: event>, u'occupation': <ContentType: occupation>, u'console': <ContentType: console>, u'meettheexperts': <ContentType: meet the experts>, u'auditlog': <ContentType: audit log entry>, u'proxyuser': <ContentType: user>, u'consoleuser': <ContentType: Console User>, u'paidby': <ContentType: paid by>, u'meettheexpertstransaction': <ContentType: Meet the experts Transaction>, u'clientuserconsole': <ContentType: client user console>, u'paymentmethod': <ContentType: payment method>, u'transaction': <ContentType: transaction>, u'country': <ContentType: Country>, u'client': <ContentType: client>, u'place': <ContentType: place>, u'consoletotal': <ContentType: console total>}
```

So a fix to the cached manager which was caching all content types has resolved the issue.